# Complexes, $z^2 = (1-i)\overline z $

Tags: linear-algebra

Given: $z^2 = (1-i)\overline z $ Prove that it has 4 solutions.

So, if $z = 0$ we have already 1 solution.

nowm if $z \ne 0$ then:

$z^3 = (1-i)|z|^2$

define: $z = rcisa$

$r^3cis3a = 
\sqrt2cis(3pai/4)$

$\sqrt2cis(3pai/4)$  -- Can anyone explain me this line please?

Comment: The polar form of (1-i)? There may be some distortion in the formatting; there should be r-squared on the right too.

Comment: well, $|z|^2 = r^2$

Comment: Indeed, so where did it go in the next line?

Comment: Well, it should be now $r^2(1-i)$

Comment: How do I go on from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right number is $\frac{7\pi}{4}$, because $\sin\frac{7\pi}{4}=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$, $\cos\frac{7\pi}{4}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$ and so

$$1-i=\sqrt{2}(\cos\frac{7\pi}{4}+i\sin\frac{7\pi}{4}).$$

In general, let $z$ and $w$ be complex numbers. For some $\alpha, \beta, r_z$, and $r_w$ we have:
$$
z=x+iy=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cdot(\cos \alpha+i\sin\alpha)=r_z(\cos \alpha+i\sin\alpha);
$$
$$
w=r_w(\cos \beta+i\sin\beta).
$$
Moreover,
$$\overline{z}=x-iy=r_z(\cos (-\alpha)+i\sin(-\alpha)),$$
$$
zw=r_zr_w(\cos (\alpha+\beta)+i\sin(\alpha+\beta)),
$$
$$
z\overline{z}=r_z^2(\cos 0+i\sin 0)=r_z^2.
$$

In your example we have 
$$
z^3=z\overline{z}(1-i), \mathrm{\ i.e.,\ }
$$
$$
r_z^3(\cos (3\alpha)+i\sin(3\alpha))=\sqrt{2}r_z^2(\cos\frac{7\pi}{4}+i\sin\frac{7\pi}{4}),
$$
and so
$$
r_z=\sqrt{2},\ 3\alpha=\frac{7\pi}{4}.
$$
Equation $3\alpha=\frac{7\pi}{4}$ has 3 solution that you are looking for.

Comment: Can't understand yet. How did it got to 3pai/4?

Comment: It is a misprint, it should be 7pai/4.

Comment: It is [argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)) of complex number 1-i.

Comment: Can you explain how you got this?  $\sin\frac{7\pi}{4}=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$, $\cos\frac{7\pi}{4}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$ I can't use a calculator in the exam though.

Comment: $\frac{7\pi}{4}=2\pi-\frac{\pi}{4}\sim-\frac{\pi}{4}$, and use $\sin(-\alpha)=-\sin\alpha$, $\cos(-\alpha)=\cos\alpha$.

Comment: http://ege-study.ru/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/trigonometr.jpg

Comment: Spasiba @Ibazhov !